# Border layout south panel collapsible via splitter but without title

Tags: extjs

I have a south panel that does not have a title since it holds other panels.

The problem is that if I enable `collapsible: true`, it shows the title even if the title is set to null, I guess this is because the injected title toggle button.

Since there's also a splitter hide button, the title is actually not needed at all.

So anyway to keep the title always hidden and use just the splitter button?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2j3m)

**Code snippet:**

```
{
    region: 'south',
    collapsible: true,
    header: false,
    split: true,
    height: 200,
    minHeight: 120,
    title: 'South'
}
```